# Looking for best practices when working with TFS source control

Tags: version-control, tfs

I'm looking for a good summary of best practices for working with TFS source control:

Examples:

- Get latest before checking in
- Make sure everything builds after getting latest but before checking in

etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [patterns & practices VSTS Guidance Project](http://www.codeplex.com/VSTSGuidance) and [patterns & practices Team Development with TFS Guide](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSGuide).

Comment: Perfect...  Exactly what I've been looking for.

Thanks!